# Nothing happens when entering the babel command

Tags: node.js, windows, webpack, babeljs

I just installed babel as followed: `npm install -g babel-cli`

However when I try to enter the babel command in either nodejs cmd (as admin) or my editor pycharm's terminal, nothing happens.. It's like it's loading or something but even waiting for more than 20min. nothing appeares.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KgMZ.png)

This started happening after I added `C:\Users\sebas\PycharmProjects\storage\node_modules\.bin` as a path to the environment variables

Before that, every time I tried running babel I would get a `babel command not recognized as an external or internal command` error.

**What is going on?**

Comment: That is not how babel-cli works. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli Check the documentation. You have to specify the file/s

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the easiest way to solve this (see: not adding to your path) is to simply add an entry inside your `package.json`

For example:

```
  ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "babel src -d lib --copy-files",
  },
  ...
```

This way, all you need to do is run `npm run build`, and it will take care of figuring out where `babel` is. Also, remember to add a `.babelrc` with the following content if you're using `babel-preset-env`:

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Comment: That didn't help, by the way I rewrote my question completely from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely because you have not added the `.\node_modules\.bin` directory to your path.

Until you do that, you can use `.\node_modules\.bin\babel`

Comment: I had in fact not added the `.\node_modules\.bin` to my path. And it somehow solved it ... now instead of getting the error, nothing is happening. It seems like it's loading, but even after waiting like 5 minutes, nothing is happening. [screenshot of it](https://gyazo.com/04d2b4630a86a7286c61e99d88b692cc) (Yes, I did restart both the nodejs cmd and my editor before retyping the command)